# Pointer isn't pointing

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have this 'ere code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


// Library stuff

typedef struct {
    int x, y;
} _TYPE_position;

typedef struct {
    char image[32];
    _TYPE_position position;
} _TYPE_object;

_TYPE_object *object;

int createObject(const _TYPE_object *insertionObject);
int createObject(const _TYPE_object *insertionObject) {
    int index;
    _TYPE_object *newObjectPtr = realloc(object, sizeof(*object) + sizeof(_TYPE_object));
    if(newObjectPtr != NULL) {
        object = newObjectPtr;
        index = sizeof(*object) / sizeof(_TYPE_object) - 1;
        strcpy(object[index].image, insertionObject->image);
        object[index].position = insertionObject->position;
    }
    else {
        index =- 1;
    }
    return index;
}


// Demo program

int main(void) {

    _TYPE_object smile = {
        "smile.png", { 112, 80 }
    };

    int smileIndex = createObject(&smile);

    if(smileIndex == -1) {
        printf("Error allocating memory for smile object");
        while(1);
    }

    smile.position.x = 55; // Does nothing since the object does not point here for some reason

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(*object) / sizeof(_TYPE_object); i++) {
        printf("Create %s at { %d, %d }\n", object[i].image, object[i].position.x, object[i].position.y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And it kind of works. It seems that object is not pointing to a _TYPE_object but is instead creating an exact copy of it.

Is there a way to make the object array point to objects, rather than just recreating them. So in the above example have smile.position.x = 55; actually change the value that gets printed.

Comment: `index = sizeof(*object) / sizeof(_TYPE_object) - 1;` index will always be zero (since sizeof/sizeof will always be one.)

Comment: Prefixing type names with `_TYPE_` is awkward and in violation of the standard, in which symbols beginning with `_` followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: To find the index I use: sizeof(*object) / sizeof(_TYPE_object) - 1 because object may contain a reference to more than 1 object, and then I divide that by the size of each individual object to see how many objects are there.

Comment: Also, thanks for the pointer (see what I did there) about variable names. I'll be sure to change that once I have fixed the problem.

Comment: Remember: sizeof is an operator, applied at compile time. Its result is effectively a constant. The syntax does not say: `sizeof object`, but `sizeof expression`.

Comment: `sizeof()` doesn't do what you think it does. For a pointer `p` on type `t`, `sizeof(*p)` always return the size in bytes of 1 element `t`, which is the same thing as `sizeof(t)`.

Comment: @wildplasser: not necessarily constant; c99 allows variable size arrays. But this will indeed never return the size of a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: @SamuelTardieu: I knew that, but didn't want to confuse the OP, who already is confused. (in this case, there is no VLA,BTW)

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the `sizeof()` problems, the issue here is that you are making an explicit copy of the `_TYPE_Object` fields given to `createObject()`, including the position, by doing:

```
object[index].position = insertionObject->position;
```

So there is no reason for the position in the copy (which is what you are printing) to be modified when you change the original (through `smile.position.x = 55`).

If you want to insert a reference to the original object and not make a copy, then you must make an array of pointers instead of an array of objects themselves.

Comment: What type would it need to be to declare object? int *object[]?

Answer (score 1):

```
index = sizeof(*object) / sizeof(_TYPE_object) - 1;
```

I believe you intend for this to tell you how many objects are already allocated, but you are incorrect.  `*object` does not refer to the whole array, but instead only `object[0]`, the first item in the array.  It also does not deference or calculate with the expression inside `sizeof` at all, so your code is equivalent to:

```
index = sizeof(_TYPE_object) / sizeof(_TYPE_object) - 1;
```

I recommend you use something like this:

```
int objects_allocated = 0;
int objects_used = 0;
_TYPE_object *object = NULL;
```

You are also using a lot of unnecessary `sizeof` expressions.  You need `sizeof` to determine the size of allocations, but when you're indexig into the array you don't need it.  In other words:

```
&(object[n]) == ((void *)object) + n*sizeof(_TYPE_object)
```

You also don't need to explicitly copy each member over.  You can use:

```
object[index] = *insertionObject;
```

Comment: Well this helps. But I'm not trying to copy each member over. I want the object array to reference the _TYPE_object variables.

Comment: Then you want `_type_OBJECT **object`, `object = realloc(object, sizeof (_type_OBJECT *) * num_objects`, and `object[index] = insertionObject`